# Custom UIView not showing

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I created a custom UIView with a label in the IB. (MyView)

I drag a UIView from the Objects window onto my Initial View -> View Controller ( Storyboard).

I set the UiView ( I just dragged ) to my custom View "MyView".

When it runs or in design mode, I cannot see my label on my custom view nor in the storyboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't help without more information about the problem and what you have already tried to solve it.

Comment: I think he's created a file for his UIView in IB. Then he's added a UIView to the ViewController IB file and changed the type to MyView. You can't do that though. The only one being created is the one on the UIViewController with no label. If you want to add it using IB then you need to do it ALL in the UIViewController. Or you can create the UIView in IB and then add it in code. You can't create in IB and then add in IB too.

Comment: Is your first sentence an overview of what you did, or is that a different view from the one you describe in your second sentence?

Comment: more of a step. I tried to say I created a custom UIView and then I want to add it to my ViewController in my storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating that custom view in a xib, if you want to add it to a controller in the storyboard (you could do that, but then you would have to add the custom view in code). Just add the view to the view controller, add the label to the view, and then change the class of that view to MyView, all in the storyboard.

Comment: fair enough. But I wanted to use it like a control in Visual Studio, so I create the control and I have the control and create it so this applies project wide. This isn't possible in xCode? Like a user control in win forms.net?

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio, but you can't make a view and add it to the objects list, and use it wherever any more -- this used to be possible, but not in the latest versions of Xcode. So, if you want to use it throughout your app, you'll have to add it in code, or copy and paste the view from the xib file into your storyboard.